# Limiting user from 0-100 in input function

Tags: python, input

How to create a program that limiting user in input function from 0-100 only. We need to ask user to for their grade in 4 tests after that if the user does not have taken any of those test it shows INC.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    score = float(input('Enter your score: '))
    if not 0 <= score <= 100:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    score = input('Enter your score: ')
    if not (0 <= score <= 100):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: How your code is resolving or addressing the query of OP?